# Check other input fields other than the one being typed in and if exists remove value

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to check to make sure that a value that a user inputs does not appear in another text field if if it does then remove then remove the text that the user typed. I'm looping through the fields like this:

```
$( ".sort_member_order_text" ).keyup(function() {
    var dInput = this.value;
    $(".sort_member_order_text").each(function() {
        var fInput = this.value;
        if(fInput == dInput){
            fInput.html('');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

I tried the above code but I'm getting an undefined. Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: `if(dInput.indexOf(fInput) !== -1)` will evaluate to true if fInput is found inside of dInput

Comment: Add a `.not(this)` to that `.each` - else it'll include the field being typed in and wipe it everytime.

Comment: @tymeJV How would I reset the value in the dInput then? If I replace `fInput.html('')` with `$(this).val('')` it replaces the checked input and not the input where the keyup occured in.